# Why won't my arrow gain an objective?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to summon a wither skeleton on top of an arrow by the time it lands in the ground. It can be summoned in-flight or upon arrival, I don't really care. Every method I've tried so far involves assigning the arrow an objective, but it has not taken any of the objectives, so the skeleton cannot be summoned.

---

> `Shadow_Mage` is the team of the player shooting the arrow
> `Sarrow` is the objective I'm trying to assign; it's type `dummy`
>
> Running in an always-active unconditional repeating block:
> `execute @a[team=Shadow_mage] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players set @e[type=Arrow,r=3] Sarrow 1 {inGround:1b}`
>
> Running in an another always-active unconditional repeating block:
> `execute @e[type=Arrow,score_Sarrow_min=1,score_Sarrow=1] ~ ~ ~ (valid summon command here)`
>
> After that I'm going to execute `@` the skeleton to `kill` the nearest `arrow`.

When I run `testfor @e[r=5,type=Arrow,score_Sarrow_min=1]` I get no responses - even though I am of the team `Shadow_mage` and the arrow is within `5` meters.

---

Is my command setup wrong, so the arrow isn't being assigned the objective?
Is the objective being set, but I'm interacting with it wrong?
Is there a better way to reach the right end result?

Comment: Your commands are correct syntax-wise. Your score assigning command will only target arrows in the ground within 3 blocks of a Shadow Mage, but your testfor is looking within 5. Try moving closer and testing again. I would suggest also switching to a scoreboard tag. They are great for one-state marking and don't require a dummy objective. Finally, I would suggest using a command chain, instead of two separate repeating commands. It would ensure that the commands execute in the correct order, although this is not necessary. (I wrote this in a comment because it's not an actual solution)

Comment: @SB32 Thanks. The testfor still has / had no output at any distance. I'm willing to try scoreboard tags but I'm unfamiliar; maybe that part could become the answer.

Comment: my guess would be that `Shadow_Mage` is not capitalised correctly in your execute command. also, this will summon a skeleton at every arrow that is in a 3 block range of the mage in the ground, is that what you wanted it to do?

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is have an extra scoreboard command (Warrow) and then go from there.

Put the command `execute @a[team=Shadow_mage] ~ ~ ~ scoreboard players set @e[type=Arrow,r=2] Sarrow 1` into a repeating command block with the following commands in order into 3 chain command blocks after it:

`/scoreboard players set @e[type=Arrow,score_Sarrow_min=1,score_Sarrow=1] Warrow 1 {inGround:1b}`

`execute @e[type=Arrow,score_Warrow_min=1,score_Warrow=1] ~ ~ ~ summon Wither ~ ~ ~`

`kill @e[type=Arrow,score_Warrow_min=1,score_Warrow=1]`

The first command finds out which arrows are shot by team Shadow_mage (or near them, unfortunately), and sets their score of Sarrow to 1, then the second command gives those arrows a score of 1 in Warrow when they hit the ground, the third command summons the Wither, and the last command kills the arrow to stop it from constantly summoning Withers